# C# callback for when a class with attribute got instantiated

Tags: c#, class, callback, attributes, initialization

Is there something like a callback for when when a class `Foo` with a specific attribute got instantiated?
A little like this pseudo code:

```
void OnObjectWithAttributeInstantiated(Type attributeType, object o) {
    // o is the object with the attribute
}
```

So i was trying to create an attribute `AutoStore`. Imagine the following:

Given a class `Foo` with that tag:

```
[AutoStore]
public class Foo { ... }
```

Then (somewhere else in the code, no matter where) you instantiate that class

```
Foo f = new Foo()
```

I now want, that this object `f` will be automatically added to a list of objects (e.g. in a static class or something)

If there is no such way, do you have some ideas how to do a work-around?

**Edit**
I dont want to use a superclass which does that for purposes of clean code

Best regards Briskled

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible. Attributes are baked into the compiled code, so the only way to know that an object has an attribute is to query the object’s attributes. This is though the kind of thing that https://www.postsharp.net/ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Because attributes are there for you to discover at runtime. But a possible solution might be to create a factory to wrap the whole thing, like -

```cs
public class Factory
{
    public static T Instantiate<T>() where T : class
    {
        // instantiate your type
        T instant = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        // check if the attribute is present
        if (typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AutoStore), false) != null)
        {
            Container.List.Add(instant);
        }
        return instant;
    }
}

public static class Container
{
    public static List<object> List { get; set; } = new List<object>();
}
```

and then you can use it like -

```cs
Foo foo = Factory.Instantiate<Foo>();
foo.Bar = "Some Bar";
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a little sad that this is not possible but it is as it is.
Also thanks for your idea. I will keep that in mind